# An array of primes generated from a given array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes

I am trying to take a given array and iterate through it to create a new array containing only the numbers that are prime from the given array.

What I'm not sure of is the syntax for doing so - I know this is butchered and wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it? Or if I'm even going about it the right way.

```
var myArray = isPrime([1,5,17,25,30])
console.log(myArray)

function isPrime(array){
    var primes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] /= 1 || array[i] / 1 == array[i]){
            primes.push([i]);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is creating a `isElementPrime(number)` function that tells if the number is prime or not (find an [implementation here](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-function-exercise-8.php)), and loop through it!

```
function isPrime(array){
    var primes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(isElementPrime(array[i]){
            primes.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to divide the number by every number smaller than it and greater than 1 and see if there is a remainder.

Using `filter` you can apply this to all elements in the array;

See example:

```js
function isPrime(element) {
  for(var i = 2; i < element; i++) {
    if(element % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return element !== 1;
}

var array = [1, 5, 17, 25, 30];
var primes = array.filter(isPrime);

console.log("array: " + array);
console.log("primes: " + primes);
```

Comment: See, that's how I figured it'd be easier to do it, but apparently that's incorrect because the professor wants a function that takes the array itself as its parameter.

Here's his exact wording:
" A function called isPrime, that takes an array of numbers and returns an array containing the numbers that are prime. For example. The call isPrime([1, 5, 17, 25, 30]) should return [1, 5, 17]."

I know 1 isn't technically prime but I honestly am at a loss for how to work this out without going with what Ricardo said up above which seems like it's beyond the depth of a simple functions intro.

Comment: @BetaRay The answer I provided is correct. For your homework problem, you need the answer in a specific format. It should be very easy to create a function called `isPrime` that takes an array as an input given the answer I have provided here. Please make an attempt.